# In WebView when i am using wi fi the page is not loading but when i do turn on my data connection then it's work?

Tags: android, android-studio, webview, permissions

My problem is that when i am using the data connection of my phone and load the web view then its work. but when i do turn on wifi and turn off the data connection of my phone. web view is not load.My question is There is a need of another permission for the  wifi ?

This is my MainActivity :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button mBtnSubmit;
    private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mBtnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);


        mBtnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                mWebView.loadUrl("https://www.facebook.com/rvcjofficial/?ref=br_rs");

            }
        });


    }
}
```

This is my Manifest :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.aaa.webviewexample">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I given the permission of the wifi afterthat when i am using wifi the page is not loading.Can anyone tell me what is the problem ?

Comment: Please provide your list of permissions from manifest file

Comment: @n9153 Please see my updated code.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score -1):

Add the following permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```